# Link From excel to open pdf file

Tags: excel, pdf, hyperlink

I want to link to a specific page in pdf file whose link is given in excel file.i dont want page to open on browser .I want it to open up locally on my pc.

Comment: Haresh - did you ever get this working? 
I am trying to do this without VBA via Hyperlink function. Apparently the following 'should' work but isn't for me: `=HYPERLINK("filename.pdf#page=5")`

Answer (score 3):

You can link the PDF file with *Insert > Hyperlink > [path of file]* When the link is clicked and the PDF file exists at that location on the machine, the file will be opened (after the accepts it in a warning dialog).

I strongly doubt though, that it is at all possible, to link to a specific page in a PDF. But why not just specify the relevant page in a note next to the link.

**Example:**

```
Further Details, see the Documentation:
D:\Documents\Docs\Documentation.pdf
(Page 21)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a macros to start Acrobat with parameters.

When opening a PDF document from a command shell, you can pass the parameters to the open 
command using the /A switch with the following syntax:

```
<Acrobat path> /A "<parameter>=<value>" "<PDF path>"
For example:
Acrobat.exe /A "page=8" "C:\example.pdf"
```

<kbd>[link](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

A working implementation of the VBA suggestion from Andrii Horda would be...

(With Acrobat Reader DC and the links to the PDF files listed in Column E)

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Row = Target.Row
Column= "E"
Path= Range(Column & Row)
If Target.Column = "5" Then
Shell """" & Environ("ProgramFiles") & "\Adobe\Acrobat Reader 2015\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"" /A ""page=2"" """ & Path & """", vbNormalFocus
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I've done this useing "Formulas>Lookup & Referenc>Hyperlink".  This is the string I use:

FY21\WN096%20-%20McGean%20Aircraft%20Soap.pdf

With "FY21" being in 'Z:\myname\Home\Inventory tracking\Open Puchase Request\PR's'

I then put the PDF file name as "text to display"